# Laravel "with" and "where" conditions with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, conditional-statements

I have two tables linked one to many (files -> people). I need to select all files where people have a certain name but i need the whole group of that selection.

FASCICOLI:

| id | numero | anno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021 |

PEOPLE:

| id | fascicoli_id | fascicoli_numero | fascicoli_anno | cognome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020 | Urbano |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2020 | Del Mastro |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2021 | Di Ciano |

Well, if I do a search where 'cognome' LIKE '% Del' (id = 2), I must also receive the other records with the same fascicoli_id (therefore both 'Del Mastro' and 'Urbano').

I have tried with the following (where $query is the search parameter I pass with GET method in ajax):

```
$fascicoli = Fascicoli :: with ('person') -> get ();
$fascicoli = $fascicoli [0] -> person () -> where ('cognome', 'like', '%'. $query. '%') -> get ();
```

and

```
$fascicoli = Fascicoli :: whereHas ('person', function ($ sub) use ($query) {
    $sub-> where ('cognome', 'like', '%'. $query. '%')
}) -> get ();
```

Comment: The space in $sub is a typo? Do you get an error? Explain exactly what the problem is

Comment: yes it is a typo. I have no errors, I need, as explained, to extract the other records with the same fascicoli_id (therefore both 'Del Mastro' and 'Urbano') from query LIKE. What is the right query?

Comment: Looks like the second query does exactly what you want?

Comment: The second query only extrapolates the record where 'fascicoli_numero = 1 and name LIKE% Del', so the result is only 'Del Mastro', while I would also need the other record where 'fascicoli_numero = 1' ('D'Urbano'). Basically I would need both.